# can paramiko has the function to implememt uploading continue from the point from last interruption

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I need implement a uploading function which can continue from the point from last interruption via sftp.

I'm trying paramiko. but I cannot fond any example about this. Can anybody give me some advices?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SFTP.open(mode='a')` opens a file in *appending* mode. So first you can call `SFTP.stat()` to get the current size of the file (on remote side) and then `open(mode='a')` it and append new data to it.

Answer (score 0):

base on whjm's advice, I wrote following code, it works. wish can help more people:

```
if filename in file_list:
    stat = sftp.stat(remot_dir + filename)
    f_local = open(local_dir + filename)
    f_local.seek(stat.st_size)
    f_remote = sftp.open(remot_dir + filename, "a")
    tmp_buffer = f_local.read(100000)
    while tmp_buffer:
        f_remote.write(tmp_buffer)
        tmp_buffer = f_local.read(100000)
    f_remote.close()
    f_local.close()
else:
    f_local = open(local_dir + filename)
    f_remote = sftp.open(remot_dir + filename, "w")
    tmp_buffer = f_local.read(100000)
    while tmp_buffer:
        f_remote.write(tmp_buffer)
        tmp_buffer = f_local.read(100000)
    f_remote.close()
    f_local.close()
```